# Error 404 using gii to create a CRUD in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, http-status-code-404, gii

I am starting with Yii2, already installed XAMPP, created a basic project named 'reservas' with the help of Yii2 project template. Then access Gii by this URL http://localhost/yiidemo/web/index.php?r=gii to generate a sample CRUD with de model 'Hotel' and the controller HotelController. I can access to http://localhost/reservas/web/index.php?r=site/index. But when i try access to http://localhost/reservas/web/index.php?r=hotel/index, a 404 sign comes out.

Comment: SiteController and HotelController are in same namespace?

Comment: Were the hotel related files actually created? if yes, check the namespace of the generated controller.